# Setup a Azure Service Fabric Listener for Service Bus Relay Binding

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azureservicebus, azure-servicebusrelay

I want to setup a Azure Service Bus Relay between my Service Fabric cluster hosted in Azure and my Private Network.

I can't get the configuration of the Service Bus Relay to work from a Service Fabric WCF service.

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return new[]
    {
        // Standard WCF Listener
        new ServiceInstanceListener(context =>
            new WcfCommunicationListener<IFooService>(
                wcfServiceObject: this,
                serviceContext: context,
                endpointResourceName: "WcfServiceEndpoint",
                listenerBinding: WcfUtility.CreateTcpListenerBinding()
            )
        ),
        // Service Bus Relay Listener
        new ServiceInstanceListener(context =>
        {
            var wcfRelay = new WcfCommunicationListener<IFooService>(
                wcfServiceObject: this,
                serviceContext: context);
            wcfRelay.ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                    typeof(IFooService),
                    new NetTcpRelayBinding(),
                    ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri(
                        "sb",
                        "{mynamespace}.servicebus.windows.net",
                        "{myservce}"))
                .Behaviors.Add(new TransportClientEndpointBehavior
                {
                    TokenProvider =
                        TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(
                            "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
                            "{mykey}")
                });

            return wcfRelay;
        })
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about what isn't working? Are you receiving some particular error? Does the same configuration work with a selfhosted WCF service in the same environment?

Comment: The self hosted WFC is working fine, as for what's not working. It's just not... No exceptions, no logs it's just silently preventing the service to start

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return new[]
    {
        new ServiceInstanceListener(context =>
        {
            var listener = new WcfCommunicationListener<IFooService>(
                serviceContext: context,
                wcfServiceObject: new FooService(),
                listenerBinding:  new WebHttpRelayBinding(EndToEndWebHttpSecurityMode.None,RelayClientAuthenticationType.None),
                address: new EndpointAddress( ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("https","[ServiceBusNamespace]","[RelayEndPoint]"))
                );

            var ep = listener.ServiceHost.Description.Endpoints.Last();

            ep.EndpointBehaviors.Add(
                new TransportClientEndpointBehavior()
                {
                    TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider("owner","[issuerSecret]")
                });
            ep.EndpointBehaviors.Add(
                new ServiceRegistrySettings(discoveryType:DiscoveryType.Public));
            ep.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

           return listener;
        })
    };
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your solution? Add some explaining text?